# Python `assert` function ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, assert

I am trying to write an `assert` function in Python to test whether the output of my function is a particular array of values.

Using `assert simulate(15,0,3) == np.array([15.,15.,15.,15.])`, I get the following error:

> `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

How do I test that a function output is an array that has more than one value?

Comment: You can assert things about the length of the array.  And as suggested, you can use `any()` and/or `all()` to assert things about elements within the array.

Answer (score 0):

the `assert` function doesn't work well when working with numpy. Use `allclose()` instead.

this should work

```
print(np.allclose(simulate(15,0,3), np.array([15,15,15,15])))
```

Comment: @Newbie. Did this response help? I would appreciate if you would upvote this. I'm new here and it would help me a lot. Thanks!